# React Apollo graphql enricher not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, redux-saga, react-apollo

For some reason the graphql higher order function is not behaving as expected, specifically the query is not even being called. This is what I have right now:

```
function viewReducer({ dispatch, value }) {
    let temp = () => (<MyPage
                          onReconnect = {() => {dispatch(restartSetup());}}
                      />);
    let View = graphql(myQuery)(temp);
    return <View />
}

export { viewReducer };
```

What exactly I'm missing here?

[graphql](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#graphqlquery-configcomponent) react-apollo documentation.

**Edit**: After some debugging it looks like props are not being passed to the actual component. Updated code for debugging:

```
function viewReducer({ dispatch, value }) {
    let temp = () => (<MyPage
                          onReconnect = {() => {dispatch(restartSetup());}}
                      />);
    let View = graphql(myQuery,
                    options: {
                        fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
                    },
                    props: (props) => {
                        console.log("[INFO] " + JSON.stringify(props))
                        return props;
                    }               
               )(temp);
    return <View />
}
```

I can see the data fetched but the props are not being passed, it's still undefined.

Comment: How are you determining the query "is not being called"? Are you not seeing the request fired in the network tab?

Comment: Before the query is fired, it fetches AWS Cognito credentials for authentication. It is a custom credentials fetcher. I can't the see the logs for that which I can see otherwise if I use the <Query> tag directly.

Comment: So, I noticed a few things. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Ah, got the issue. Look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The problem was here:

```
let temp = () => (<MyPage
                          onReconnect = {() => {dispatch(restartSetup());}}
                      />);
```

As this closure is not accepting the props as arguments, it is executed and rendered as it is. To fix this I just added the props as argument:

```
let temp = ({data}) => (<MyPage
                          onReconnect = {() => {dispatch(restartSetup());}}
                          data = {data}
                      />);
```